# how to Submiting a Form when i click on the hyperlink using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need a help to submit a form when i click on the hyper link, i have used following jquery Script  to submit the form, but the form not get submitted

```
   <script >
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tmpn').click(function()
        {
           var v=$(this).attr('id');
           $('#keywords').val(v);
           $("#searchform567").submit();
        });

     });
</script>
```

Comment: You have a bad closing tag at end and script is closed before the closing tag.

Comment: Do you want the user to follow the hyperlink or submit the form? Or both?

Comment: do you really have `</script>` inside the ready function ??

Comment: try   event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this as you have closed your script before closing of the `doc ready` handler:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.tmpn').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); //----------------or return false;
       var v=$(this).attr('id');
       $('#keywords').val(v);
       $("#searchform567").submit();
     });
   });
 </script>
```

[**Tryout Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aASka/)

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up your `<script>` tags which are not properly closed. Also if this hyperlink has an `href` property you need to cancel the default action by returning false from your click callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tmpn').click(function() {
        var v = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#keywords').val(v);
        $("#searchform567").submit();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i used return false, but form not submmited